# Hangman- No misses left

Tags: word, game, english, pencil-and-paper-games, no-computers

**** No programs allowed. You must find the answer using your own brain. ****

Your hangman game allows for 9 misses, but on the 10th miss, you're hanged!

You don't want to be hanged. The letters marked red underneath have already been guessed.

What is the English word?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I reckon the answer is

> Pizzazz
> http://www.thefreedictionary.com/pizzazz

Comment: had you seen this one before?

Comment: Nope, but was thinking of pizza at the time which helped a lot :)

Comment: Is pizzazz officially considered an English word?

Comment: See the link, it's in the Collins English Dictionary