# The hangman game backward

Tags: riddle, english, language, letters

So, @JLee has posted a hangman game ([Hangman- No misses left](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/11223/hangman-no-misses-left)) on SE.  I would like to create one too, but let's do it backward - guess what was the question, with only 1 letter missing:

fill in an "a" - you wish you have it for your lovely home
fill in an "e" - I will have some water and I am fine
fill in an "i"  - It happens only in the future you may say
Now, if you fill in a "w" - now, it's not a word but the world was crazy about it!

Your answer can be in form of:

> The question was: _ p p l e

followed by explanation.

Comment: The "game" tag says "A puzzle that asks for determining the winner in a multi-player game." I think the tags I've put are better :-)

Comment: There, and thanks!  I did not know how it should be tagged.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The question was:

> w _ ll

Explanation:

You wish you have it for your lovely home

> A home is not a home without walls.

I will have some water and I am fine

> Well holds water, well means fine

It happens only in the future you may say

> A person writes a will for when they die, not in the present moment.

Now, it's not a word but the world was crazy about it!

> wwll, or I suspect supposed to represent World War II (though those are Is, not Ls.)

Comment: Nicely done!  And yes for last line, those are roman numerals which looks like L's in small letter

Comment: It's amusing (to me) how I came up with the answer. I was sitting there thinking about it, looking around my own house for the first part. I was thinking, "Bathtub? Water? Mat? Alarm?", but nothing fit... so I rested my head on the wall, and, well, the rest just came to me. :p

Comment: Hah that was great.  Next time I will make a harder one so you can't just bump your head into the wall and got the answer =D