# The hangman game backward #2

Tags: riddle, english, language, letters

[Hangman game backward](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/11281/the-hangman-game-backward) version 2 - guess what was the question, with only 1 letter missing:

fill in a "b" - I might lose control anytime, so keep me on my toes.
fill in an "m" - my brothers are all metalhead but me.
fill in a "p" - my buddy has two big tusks and loves to carry me around all day long.
fill in a "w" - This is usually where the presidents stay.

Again, your answer can be in the form of:

> The question was: _ p p l e

followed by explanation.

Comment: This looks harder than expected!

Comment: Yes!  But someone has already got the answer!

Comment: Great problem!  I actually use all four things so they were all in my domain.  I think this solution is harder for people who aren't actually familiar with the words.

Comment: @JasonLepack Nice one! I can understand with wallet, mallet and pallet, but I am just curious if ballet applies too?

Comment: Absolutely.  Not so much now but more when I was younger.  My kids watch the wiggles now and Emma does it all the time.

Comment: Please post more of these. It was bugging the heck out of me yesterday and I'd love to see more!

Comment: @generalcrispy I'll add more of these questions later!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The question was:

> _allet

fill in a "b" - I might lose control anytime, so keep me on my toes.

> Ballet - Dancers dance on their toes all the time

fill in an "m" - my brothers are all metalhead but me.

> Mallet - Rubber or sometimes wooden headed hammer, as opposed to the metal ones.

fill in a "p" - my buddy has two big tusks and loves to carry me around all day long.

> Pallet - They are usually picked up by forklifts

fill in a "w" - This is usually where the presidents stay.

> Wallet - Presidents is a slang term for money in the USA because all of their bills have pictures of their presidents.

Comment: Nicely done and well explained, +1