# Backwards Hangman

Tags: riddle, english, language, letters

All credits to [@Alex](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/10037/alex) for inventing this type of puzzle with [the original](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/11281/the-hangman-game-backward) and [the sequel](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/12982/the-hangman-game-backward-2).

- Guess an "R" - I can only be spelled right.
- Guess an "F" - Lots of me took place in the world wars.
- Guess an "L" - Most types of me are never seen
- Guess an "M" - I'm not a yes or a no.
- Guess an "N" - I am the always to some places on the moon.

Your answer could be in the form of:

> The question was: ␣ p p l e

followed by explanation.

Comment: I would suggest you show the guessed letters as capitals.  It would make it a lot easier to read and would remove the need to clarify the L.

Comment: Slightly too easy IMO, but +1 anyway!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question was:

> _ i g h t

Guess an "r" - I can only be spelled right.

> Right can only be spelled "right".

Guess an "f" - Lots of me took place in the world wars.

> Lots of fights took place in the world wars.

Guess an "l" - Most types of me are never seen

> Most types of light are not in the visible spectrum.

Guess an "m" - I'm not a yes or a no.

> Might means maybe, not yes or no.

Guess an "n" - I am the always to some places on the moon.

> The moon is always night on the dark side.

Comment: Right. May I ask what gave it away?

Comment: Ninja'd >_<   , @Reticality, it was a fairly obvious one really... I'd say the first two (the literal 'right' and fight) were two easy, once you know or strongly guess i'ts _ight, all you need to do is check if the rest can fit in some way.

Comment: @Reticality, probably the usage of "right" within the first clue. Your brain will have the word in your subconscious as you are reading the other letters, then it will easily trigger the "oh, these other letters fit here, too". Your other puzzles didn't use any of the words, which made it tougher to think of them.

Answer (score 2):

> **_ight**

- Guess an "r" - I can only be spelled right.

> right

- Guess an "f" - Lots of me took place in the world wars.

> fight

- Guess an "l" - Most types of me are never seen

> light

- Guess an "m" - I'm not a yes or a no.

> might

- Guess an "n" - I am the always to some places on the moon.

> night

Comment: I didn't even notice the comments lol, I figured it out myself, its pretty easy.
Also my page didnt load the other answers :(