# The hangman game backward #3

Tags: riddle, english, language, letters

[Hangman game backward](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/12982/the-hangman-game-backward-2) version 3 - guess what was the question:

fill in "d" - Your white shirt soaked with my blood but you wouldn't care.
fill in "n" - It will be nice to have it on table or bedside.
fill in "t" - You're looking at me now without knowing.  In fact you are touching / smelling / hearing / tasting me without knowing.

Again, your answer can be in the form of:

> The question was: _ p p l e

followed by explanation.

Comment: I hope there are no tricks like "wwll" this time? :-)

Comment: @randal'thor Looks like we weren't so lucky.

Comment: These backward hangman puzzles are really fun and ingenious.

Comment: @AggieKidd We should have noticed that now it says just 'fill in "d"' instead of 'fill in **a** "d"'! +1 to your answer anyway.

Comment: Oh man nothing can escape your eyes rand al'thor?  I silently removed them and guess it didnt' work :D

Comment: Thanks @dennisdeems I tried to make it harder but guess people are just too smart on SE

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Could it be

> m a _ _ e r

with "d"

> madder - a red dye or pigment obtained from the root of the madder plant, or a synthetic dye resembling it.
>  presumably you are soaking your white shirt with this red dye (the color of blood!) because you *want* to dye your shirt red.

with "n"

> manner - table manners and bedside manners are both good things to have

with "t"

> matter - everything is made of matter!

Comment: Brilliant! This has to be it.

Comment: Ah! *Two* blanks! Well done.

Comment: @EngineerToast I just edited the answer to make it more apparent

Answer (score 10):

Maybe a bit of a stretch, but is it

> ti_e

fill in "d" - Your white shirt soaked with my blood but you wouldn't care.

> tide - the magical laundry detergent will get out blood.

fill in "n" - It will be nice to have it on table or bedside.

> tine - fork on a table, some other pokey thing by the bed for... well....

fill in "t" - You're looking at me now without knowing. In fact you are touching / smelling / hearing / tasting me without knowing.

> tite - a bit of an old word, but defined as "immediate" [here](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/tite). We touch, smell, hear, and taste the present or immediate.

Comment: I like how 4 people agreed with your +1, and somehow the answer only has 2 upvotes!

Comment: If the second line works out I'll have had created a riddle with 2 answer unknowingly.  "Tide" just match perfectly here!

Comment: @Alex If it had been an 'm' rather than an "n", then I think it would have worked perfectly. The "n" doesn't quite fit though :-(

Comment: @AggieKidd 'm' as in 'time'?

Comment: @Alex Yeah. Most have a clock on their bedside table, and you want to have time to sit at a table.

Comment: @AggieKidd you gave me an idea - to create a set that can fit with 2 answers!

Comment: @Alex Very nice. Good luck, that sounds like a challenge to come up with as much as to solve.