# The hangman game backward #9

Tags: riddle, knowledge, english, language, letters

Hangman game backward #9 - guess what was the question:

fill in "i" - a famous city in New York, Illinois and Nevada.
fill in "o" - half of the population said to have experience being one.
fill in "u" - You might not see it at night in the dark.

Again, your answer can be in the form of:

> The question was: _ p p l e

First answer that fully explained each line will be accepted, enjoy!

Comment: See:  http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/11281/the-hangman-game-backward

Comment: @Khale_Kitha Check out the older question and its answer: http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/12982/the-hangman-game-backward-2.  It will give you an idea

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Is it, perhaps:

> s_n?

fill in "i" - a famous city in New York, Illinois and Nevada.

> Sin city. New York City and Chicago were both previously known as sin city, and now Las Vegas holds that title. Thanks to Chris Cudmore for confirming my guess

fill in "o" - half of the population said to have experience being one.

> Half the population consists of sons, the other half daughters

fill in "u" - You might not see it at night in the dark.

> Rarely see the sun at night

Comment: There is a Sin City Strip club in NY, a Sin City Resort in Il, and Las Vegas is commonly called Sin City.  So this looks good to me.

Comment: @ChrisCudmore Those aren't cities at all. At most, Las Vegas counts for this.

Comment: This is puzzling.  Words can have different meanings.  "Famous Hat in Hollywood"  could be "The Brown Derby" (A restaurant)

Comment: this is indeed the correct answer!  However I'll accept it once you figured out the first line.  I'll give you a hint: Chicago, New York city, Las Vegas

Comment: @Alex Is Chris Cudmore on the right track?

Comment: @StephenTG you had the right answer on line 1, just missing explanation.    See my hints on last comment

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sin_City_(description) 

Lists New York and Chicago as 'Former Sin Cities'  and Las Vegas is well known as the current Sin City

Comment: @ChrisCudmore OK, this makes sense as reasoning for the answer; the strip club thing didn't.

Comment: Fill in "a" - Part of many west coast cities.  Fill in "e" - You may find them in the Capital.