# The Hangman Game Backwards Again

Tags: riddle, english, language, letters

It's been a while since one of these puzzles (created by [Alex](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/10037/alex), see [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/11281/the-hangman-game-backward) for the first) has shown up, and I thought some might enjoy another one.

fill in an "n" - You don't need to throw me out into the bin.
fill in an "f" - You wish you could see my insides.
fill in an "m"  - I may seem very familiar.
fill in an "v"  - Your soul now belongs to me.

As always, your answer can be in form of:

> The question was: _ p p l e

followed by explanation.

Comment: Ohhh it feels like karma that I'm stuck with it now

Comment: @Alex You've done well. I really like these puzzles.

Comment: Did you make this after seeing BaileyM's answer to my latest (which is basically the same kind of puzzle only not advertised as such)?

Comment: @randal'thor I'd been wanting to do one since they popped up the first time, but that did help inspire me a bit.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> The question was sa_e

fill in an "n" - You don't need to throw me out into the bin.

> sane - don't need to go to the looney bin

fill in an "f" - You wish you could see my insides.

> safe - I would love to see the insides of many fancy safes

fill in an "m" - I may seem very familiar.

> same - things that are the same are quite familiar.

fill in an "v" - Your soul now belongs to me.

> save - If I save your soul, it may belong to me at that point.

Comment: Very well done!