# Don't get caught by the Hang Man

Tags: riddle, english, letters, seasonal

Bringing back the Backwards Hangman (created by [Alex](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/10037/alex), see [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/11281/the-hangman-game-backward) for the first).

fill in an "f" - The devil may carry.
fill in a "d" - Probably has glasses.
fill in a "c" - Popped at the party.
fill in a "w" - A lot of this went into the first 3.

As always, your answer should be in form of:

> The question was: _ p p l e

followed by explanation of how it fits each clue.

Comment: Boy, I learned a lesson on this one... When you know an answer, don't get caught up making references to *Danny Phantom*, even if it is season-appropriate, because seeing three answers roll in kinda makes it irrelevant.  Nice puzzle, though.  I'll have to start using the term pitchdork.

Comment: @raisinghellyer PitchDork - a person of such genius they would be an evil genius, but they can't figure out how socially to conquer the world.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

the question was

> _ o r k

fill in an "f" - The devil may carry.

> the devil's pitchfork

fill in a "d" - Probably has glasses.

> dork / nerd stereotypically wears glasses

fill in a "c" - Popped at the party.

> cork from a wine bottle

fill in a "w" - A lot of this went into the first 3.

> work, it certainly did!

Comment: Dang. Three in the space of a minute. Well done to you, and too easy by me.

Comment: I believe you were first, so the tick goes to you.

Answer (score 10):

Question:

> _ o r k
>
>  The devil carries a pitchfork 
>
>  A dork wears glasses 
>
>  You pop the cork off champagne at a party 
>
>  You put work into this question

Comment: Dang. Three in the space of a minute. Well done to you, and too easy by me.

Answer (score 7):

> _ ork
>  Devil carries a (pitch)fork
>  Dorks often have glasses
>  Corks are popped when opening champagne
>  Work was done for this puzzle.

Comment: Dang. Three in the space of a minute. Well done to you, and too easy by me.