# Yet another backwards hangman

Tags: riddle, word, english, language, cryptic-clues

Insprired by the [previous backwards hangman](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/23681/dont-get-caught-by-the-hang-man) (created originally by [Alex](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/10037/alex), see [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/11281/the-hangman-game-backward)), which was solved so quickly, I though I'd make another one.  Hopefully slightly harder!  Three solutions in a minute suggests more demand is there and more supply needed.  I've made the clues a little more cryptic:

Fill in an "x" - Grows good for your car
Fill in a "g"  - Your just deserts, and what to do to war!
Fill in a "k" - Emerges only after they're gone
Fill in an "l" - Land of the dragon
Fill in a "r" - Pottery offered for sale
Fill in a "v" - Greetings are forces of nature!
Fill in a "d" - Struggles through
Fill in an "n" - As new, but changes and diminishes.

The answer will be in the form

> W_LL

followed by an explanation...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The question was:

> WA_ES
>  waxes : good for your car to protect the coat; grows like the waxing moon
>  wages : you earned them by working, and you wage war
>  wakes : "emerges" like awakens, and "after they're gone" like the wake of a boat. – credit @Charles Koppelman
>  Wales : has a dragon on its flag
>  wares : wares are things for sale; pottery = earthenware
>  waves : a wave of the hand, a wave on the ocean
>  wades : wading through a bog is quite a struggle
>  wanes : diminishes like the waning moon; "As new, but changes" points to "wanes" being an anagram of "as new". – credit @Zandar

Comment: Excellent. There are a few cryptic clues in there unaccounted for, so I'll give the tick in a while, hoping that some more will be explained. 13 minutes. Still too easy

Comment: For example, waxes also means grows, so the clue hints at waxes twice

Comment: Wakes - "emerges" like awakens, and "after they're gone" like the wake of a boat.

Comment: @DrXorile I considered "waxes"="grows" fairly obvious but ok

Comment: "As new, but changes" points to "wanes" being an anagram of "as new".

Comment: Great job! Hope you enjoyed it

Comment: I did!  I love these backward hangman puzzles.