# Mixed Backwards Hangmen

Tags: riddle, word, english, language, cryptic-clues

My [previous backward hangman](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/23692/yet-another-backwards-hangman) (created originally by [Alex](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/10037/alex), see [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/11281/the-hangman-game-backward)), was still solved too quickly, so I thought I'd make another tweak to make it a bit more tricky.

This time, whatever the bizarre back story is, is repeated four times.  But unfortunately the clues were mixed up.  So there are four different words with a missing letter, and cryptic clues next to them:

1. Filling in a "p" - Can you stomach rubbish!
2. Filling in a "v" - A serious hole.
3. Filling in an "s" - Feel bitter that he posted again.
4. Filling in a "t" - Shred an unpleasant sound.
5. Filling in a "g" - Centre on a short polite man without money representing the king.
6. Filling in a "k" - Find gold and make a coin.
7. Filling in a "p" - Of wrath: oppressive.
8. Filling in a "c" - Quick! Triple ice!
9. Filling in an "f" - Cockney view of his spouse's trouble.
10. Filling in a "c" - Regarding a small coin from not long ago.
11. Filling in a "p" - Relevant without Sn mixed in a feeling of regret.
12. Filling in a "b" - A confused biter of people.
13. Filling in a "c" - Elegant period to rethink.
14. Filling in an "l" - There next to a fasting period without the abandon.
15. Filling in a "p" - Way mature decoration.
16. Filling in an "a" - Parallel lines on a surface.
17. Filling in a "t" - Petri tests without bugs is not serious.
18. Filling in a "d" - Level or slope?

The answer will be in the form

> W_LL; _ALL; WA_ES; CU_

followed by an explanation of which word fits in to which clue...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sup>*With thanks to @DrunkWolf, who got three of the Hangman patterns, but mixed up some of the clues*</sup>

---

The four Hangman words are

> **`RE_ENT`**
>  **`GRA_E`**
>  **`STRI_E`**
>  **`TRI_E`**

1. Filling in a "p" - Can you stomach rubbish!

   > **`TRIPE`**  Tripe is made from animal stomach, and is used figuratively to mean "rubbish".
2. Filling in a "v" - A serious hole.

   > **`GRAVE`**  As an adjective, serious.  As a noun, a hole where someone is buried.
3. Filling in an "s" - Feel bitter that he posted again.

   > **`RESENT`**  To feel bitter is to resent.  Posted again = re-sent.
4. Filling in a "t" - Shred an unpleasant sound.

   > **`GRATE`**  An unpleasant sound grates on your ears.  To grate is to shred.
5. Filling in a "g" - Centre on a short polite man without money representing the king.

   > **`REGENT`**  Polite man = gentleman.  Shortened, it is gent.  "Centre" without "cent" is "re" -> "re gent".  A man representing the king is a regent.
6. Filling in a "k" - Find gold and make a coin.

   > **`STRIKE`**  Strike it rich / Strike a coin.
7. Filling in a "p" - Of wrath: oppressive.

   > **`GRAPE`**  "Grapes of wrath"; not sure about the "oppressive" part.
8. Filling in a "c" - Quick! Triple ice!

   > **`TRICE`** "Quick" is "in a trice".  Sounds like "triple ice".
9. Filling in an "f" - Cockney view of his spouse's trouble.

   > **`STRIFE`**  "Trouble" = strife; in cockney rhyming slang, a wife is "trouble and strife".
10. Filling in a "c" - Regarding a small coin from not long ago.

    > **`RECENT`**  "Re: cent" = regarding a small coin.  Recent = not long ago.
11. Filling in a "p" - Relevant with Sn mixed in a feeling of regret.

    > **`REPENT`**  One repents when one has a feeling of regret.  Not sure where the tin (Sn) fits in...
12. Filling in a "b" - A confused biter of people.

    > **`TRIBE`**  The word "biter" mixed up (confused).  People = tribe.
13. Filling in a "c" - Elegant period to rethink.

    > **`GRACE`**  Elegant = graceful.  Period to rethink = grace period.
14. Filling in an "l" - There next to a fasting period without the abandon.

    > **`RELENT`** "There" without "the" = "re".  Fasting period = lent.  Abandon = relent.
15. Filling in a "p" - Way mature decoration.

    > **`STRIPE`** A stripe is a decoration.  Not sure about "way mature".
16. Filling in an "a" - Parallel lines on a surface.

    > **`STRIAE`** Self-explanatory.
17. Filling in a "t" - Petri tests without bugs is not serious.

    > **`TRITE`**  "Petri tests" with "pests" removed leaves "trite".  Trite = not serious.
18. Filling in a "d" - Level or slope?

    > **`GRADE`**  Ground "at grade" is level; a grade in school (1st grade, etc.) is a level of learning; a grade on a road or ramp is the slope.

Comment: Glad it helped :) and yeah I was mostly just writing out thoughts, for instance I thought grape could mean thrash as in grapeshot, and was food enough related

Comment: Great job. For 7. Grapes of wrath refers to oppression; For 11: I messed it up a bit. It was meant to be pertinent with*out* tin=perent which is an anagram of repent. For 15: way =st(reet) +ripe

Comment: Ah, nice. I had all the patterns as it turns out, but couldn’t explain REPENT, STRIPE, or TRITE.

Answer (score 1):

Not a complete solution, just a start, as much for my own benefit as others.

Two of the words are:

> RE_ENT and GRA_E

The clues that fit these two are:

Filling in an "s" - Feel bitter that he posted again.

> re**s**ent

Filling in a "g" - Centre on a short polite man without money representing the king.

> re**g**ent

Filling in a "c" - Regarding a small coin from not long ago.

> re**c**ent

Filling in a "p" - Relevant with Sn mixed in a feeling of regret.

> re**p**ent

Filling in a "v" - A serious hole.

> gra**v**e

Filling in a "p" - Can you stomach rubbish!

> gra**p**e

Filling in a "t" - Shred an unpleasant sound.

> gra**t**e

Filling in a "c" - Elegant period to rethink.

> gra**c**e

I think a third word is

> STRI_E, but i'm far less sure about this one, but it could be stri**f**e for clue #9 and stri**k**e for #6, maybe..

Which leaves clues:

> Filling in a "c" - Quick! Triple ice!
>
> Filling in a "p" - Of wrath: oppressive.
>
> Filling in a "b" - A confused biter of people.
>
> Filling in an "l" - There next to a fasting period without the abandon.
>
> Filling in a "p" - Way mature decoration.
>
> Filling in an "a" - Parallel lines on a surface.
>
> Filling in a "t" - Petri tests without bugs is not serious.
>
> Filling in a "d" - Level or sl