# The hangman game backward # 11

Tags: riddle, knowledge, english, language, letters

It's been a while!  [Hangman game backward](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/11281/the-hangman-game-backward) #11 - guess what the question was:

fill in "c" - Some said I'm black, others said I'm white.  Either way you'll find it hard to lose me.
fill in "j" - You sometimes start with knocking, even though you're not in front of my house.
fill in "p" - I can be delicious, and annoying
fill in "w" - You do this before you head out for work in the morning.

Again, your answer can be in the form of:

> The question was: _ p p l e

First answer that fully explained each line will be accepted, enjoy!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think the question was:

> _ o k e

Because ...

> **C**OKE can be black (Coca-Cola) or white (cocaine), but either can be a hard habit to break.
>  **J**OKE often begins "knock-knock".
>  **P**OKE someone to annoy them; a *poke* is also a kind of berry.
>  **W**OKE you did, before getting ready for work.

Comment: That was quick!  Nicely done. And yes, because coke is the answer