# The Late Queen Gives in to Remorse - Reverse Hangman

Tags: riddle, english, language, letters

> Add a "C", I am what has been,
>   Add a "G", I might be a queen,
>   Add a "P", I'll turn away from sin
>   Add an "L" and I may just give in.

This is a *Reverse Hangman* puzzle, see [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/11281/the-hangman-game-backward) for an example.

The final answer will be a string with one letter blank which can be filled in in several different ways to form a valid word (e.g, "_at" can make **b**at, **c**at, **f**at, **h**at, etc).

**In your answer, please give the string with the missing letter and explain each line.**

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The answer is:

> re_ent

Add a "C", I am what has been,

> Recent: something that has happened in the immediate past.

Add a "G", I might be a queen,

> Regent: a person that could govern if the current monarch is unable to fulfill their duties.

Add a "P", I'll turn away from sin

> Repent: when you repent of your sins, it means you're regretful and you will probably turn away from sinning again.

Add an "L" and I may just give in.

> Relent: relenting can mean giving in to a request, yielding.