# Hangman game backward #12

Tags: riddle, knowledge, language, english, letters

Time to get back to Puzzling! [Hangman game backward](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/11281/the-hangman-game-backward) #12 - guess what the question was:

fill in "a" - In some area it proves to be a big problem to kids / teens or even adults these day, which potentially does not exists thirty something years ago.

fill in "e" - 2, 4 and 6 are the common numbers here; With 8 or more it gets a little more scary.

fill in "o" - It has different meanings - some say it's related to numbers in a different way; some said it's a variable resource; some said it's for remembering what's been done.

Again, your answer can be in the form of:

> The question was: _ p p l e

First answer that fully explained each line will be accepted, enjoy!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I believe the question was

> **L _ G**

fill in "a" - In some area it proves to be a big problem to kids / teens or even adults these day, which potentially does not exists thirty something years ago.

> Lots of gamers of all ages experience LAG when playing online multiplayer games, which did not really exist back in the 90s.

fill in "e" - 2, 4 and 6 are the common numbers here; With 8 or more it gets a little more scary.

> Most animals have 2, 4, or 6 LEGs. More than that, and you got yourself a <s>nope</s> spider or a <s>nopenope</s> centi/millipede

fill in "o" - It has different meanings - some say it's related to numbers in a different way; some said it's a variable resource; some said it's for remembering what's been done.

> LOG can mean the logarithm function, a tree trunk that is a “variable” i.e. renewable source of wood, or to record so as to remember what was done.

Comment: Nice and quick!  And yes, they're nopenope